# LDA consistency in Pyspark

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-mllib, text-mining, lda

I am using **pyspark** (version **2.3.1**) and I am trying to reproduce the same results given the following code:

```
lda = LDA(k=10, seed=5, optimizer="em", featuresCol="features")
ldamodel = lda.fit(rescaledData)
ldatopics = ldamodel.describeTopics()
ldatopics.show(10)
```

Output 1:

```
+-----+--------------------+--------------------+
|topic|         termIndices|         termWeights|
+-----+--------------------+--------------------+
|    0|[0, 199, 2, 35, 1...|[0.02179604286102...|
|    1|[267, 142, 76, 50...|[0.01640698273265...|
|    2|[14, 6, 12, 29, 7...|[0.01542644578135...|
|    3|[279, 193, 21, 74...|[0.01304181652577...|
|    4|[12, 70, 252, 151...|[0.01104580800704...|
|    5|[9, 75, 474, 255,...|[0.01606660426132...|
|    6|[13, 4, 88, 3, 27...|[0.02825736583107...|
|    7|[42, 146, 26, 700...|[0.01156411695149...|
|    8|[89, 2, 82, 403, ...|[0.01666772169015...|
|    9|[1, 303, 411, 83,...|[0.02547416776649...|
+-----+--------------------+--------------------+
```

Even if **I used the seed**, every time I restart the application (close and re-open the notebook) I have different results. Look at the 2nd Output:

```
+-----+--------------------+--------------------+
|topic|         termIndices|         termWeights|
+-----+--------------------+--------------------+
|    0|[403, 199, 414, 1...|[0.01236421045802...|
|    1|[75, 109, 251, 5,...|[0.01551907510059...|
|    2|[12, 188, 6, 314,...|[0.01206780033644...|
|    3|[91, 76, 23, 82, ...|[0.01244511461388...|
|    4|[162, 127, 12, 14...|[0.01380643020451...|
|    5|[4, 46, 7, 220, 2...|[0.01591219626409...|
|    6|[89, 71, 272, 279...|[0.02027028435250...|
|    7|[1, 3, 13, 57, 27...|[0.02192425215634...|
|    8|[2, 0, 35, 87, 65...|[0.02033711369900...|
|    9|[194, 15, 37, 42,...|[0.01436615776405...|
+-----+--------------------+--------------------+
```

Notice that I have the same problem in the **.transform** phase (even using the seed). The code used was the following:

```
paramMap = {ldamodel.seed: 5}
ldaResults = ldamodel.transform(rescaledData, params=paramMap)
```

Do you have any hint to help me?

Many thanks,
Lorenzo

Comment: I saw the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47784718/lda-model-prediction-nonconsistance) but it seems it does not work on my notebook!

Comment: I answered similar question here [latent-dirichlet-allocation-lda-in-spark-replicate-model](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54515934/latent-dirichlet-allocation-lda-in-spark-replicate-model) . Hope it helps.